# How can I post form data to a Python script on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: python, azure, cgi

I am new to Python on Azure. I have three files sitting in my wwwroot directory as below. I simply want to POST some fields from a form and retrieve them with the CGI module. This works fine on an Apache server but returns an empty FieldStorage instance on Azure.

**index.py**

```
import cgi

def main(environ, start_response):

    markup_file = open("markup.txt")
    markup = markup_file.read()
    markup_file.close()

    fields = cgi.FieldStorage()

    start_response(b"200 OK", [(b"Content-Type", b"text/html")])
    yield (markup + str(fields)).encode("utf-8")
```

**markup.txt**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Message: <input type="text" name="message" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="pythonpath" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="index.main" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Is there a configuration setting or some other obvious thing that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it seems to be a WSGI Handle script, not a CGI script.

So please follow the sections [`WSGI Handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#wsgi-handler) & [`Web.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#webconfig) of the offical document [Configuring Python with Azure App Service Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure) to rewrite your code and re-deploy it.

If you have to use CGI within Azure website, the MS MVP's [blog](https://coderead.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/hosting-go-or-any-cgi-apps-on-windows-azure-websites/) may help you.